# Input.GetKeyDown is won't work properly Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my square jump in Unity 2D when I press Space button. I have the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpSpeed;
    float moveX;
    Vector2 pos;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MoveHorizontally();
        Jump();
    }
    void MoveHorizontally(){
        moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
        pos.x = moveX * moveSpeed;

        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + pos.x,transform.position.y + pos.y);
    }
    void Jump(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Debug.Log("Jumped!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I press Space button, "Jumped!" message shows up, but my square not jumping. Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

I tried using Input.GetKey function. It works, but that function keeps making my square go upwards if i keep holding Space button.

Comment: Your force will be tiny.

Comment: `When I press Space button, "Jumped!" message shows up` .. doesn't sound like your question title is true then ...

Comment: You are giving the jumpForce a low value, set it to 500 or more and you will see your jump.

Answer (score 0):

U need to assing a value to jumpforce. and of course to the moveforce. if u dont wanna jump repeatly Just name a bool for checking if u are on ground. I use mine as" private bool =  isGrounded".
and try the code below. It makes ur jump a condition as a function of touching ground.

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")) 
        isGrounded = true;
    

}
```

and here is my code for jump.

```
 public void PlayerJump() {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded) {
        isGrounded = false;
        myBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

}
```

whenever u jump it makes your bool variant false and whenever u touch ground it make ur bool true.
Make sure "Ground" must be same exactly the tag your ground has.

Comment: His problem is that the jumpForce is too low.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `AddForce()` method you don't have to multiply with "Time.deltaTime".

What you can do is the following:

First cached your "Rigidbody2D" component from your `Start()` method because if you call it every frame it will affect your game performance.

```
private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

void Start()
{
   rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

Second, instead of `Update()` method you should call the `FixedUpdate()` method which is recommended when you deal with Physics

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    MoveHorizontally();
    Jump();
}
```

Third, on your `Jump()` method as I said on top you should not multiply the jump force with `Time.deltaTime`, instead do the following:

```
public float jumpForce = 10f;
public void Jump() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up*jumpForce);
    }
}
```

You can adjust the `jumpForce` as you want.
Also `Vector2.up` is a shorthand for writing `Vector2(0, 1)`

You can read more about Vector2 here [Vector2.up Unity's Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-up.html)